# Forwarding an observable property from one object to another in Dart

Tags: dart, observable

I would like to detect a property change from one object and then forward that value (or recompute the value and pass the result) to another object's property. I saw the example from the documentation which demonstrates value forwarding:

```dart
class MyModel extends Observable {
  StreamSubscription _sub;
  MyOtherModel _otherModel;

  MyModel() {
    ...
    _sub = onPropertyChange(_otherModel, #value,
        () => notifyPropertyChange(#prop, oldValue, newValue);
  }

  String get prop => _otherModel.value;
  set prop(String value) { _otherModel.value = value; }
}
```

But I don't know where to get the oldValue and newValue from.
I suppose those should be passed as parameters to the callback of onPropertyChange (the third parameter), but that is not the case. The callback provides no parameters. Is this an oversight or am I missing something ?

Comment: Is `MyOtherModel` also observable?

Comment: Well, this example is exact copy of the onPropertyChange Dart documentation and there's no clarification about that. However, in my case, yes it is observable.

Answer (score 0):

```dart
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:observe/observe.dart';
class MyOtherModel extends Object with Observable {
  @observable
  String value;
}

class MyModel extends Object with Observable {
  StreamSubscription _sub;
  MyOtherModel _otherModel = new MyOtherModel();

  MyModel() {

    ///...
    _otherModel.changes.listen((crs) {
        crs.forEach((PropertyChangeRecord cr) => 
             notifyPropertyChange(#prop, cr.oldValue, cr.newValue));
    });
  }

  String get prop => _otherModel.value;
  set prop(String value) => _otherModel.value = value;
}

void main() {
  MyModel m = new MyModel();
  m.prop = 'bla';
  m.changes.listen(print);
  // initiate change notification
  Observable.dirtyCheck();
}
```

output

```
[#<PropertyChangeRecord Symbol("value") from: null to: bla>]
```

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but I think that the method notifyChange in your code will send incorrect change record to the current object m. I guess it should be like this:
``    _otherModel.changes.listen((crs) {
        crs.forEach((cr) => notifyChange(new PropertyChangeRecord(this, #prop, cr.oldValue, cr.newValue)));
    });``

Comment: What I want is, when _otherModel.value changes , its new value to be sent automatically as a new value to m.prop, so any bindings to m.prop to be notified for the change